# ReactJS - JavaScript - HTML: How to update a dropdown menu after selection

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**The problem:** How do I updated a dropdown menu after selection?

Sorry if this question is simple but I have been trying many different ways to make it work.
I am building a boat visualizer using [AISHub APIs](https://www.aishub.net/api). After inquiring the APIs I am able to obtain a json file with the vessels I am interested in and inject these vessels inside a table and show their marker on a `google-map`.
Now some vessel do some functions, others do something else, and I am trying to filter that using a `dropdown` menu.

Below the most important part of the code:

**GoogleMap.js**:

```
class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true,
            buttonClickedAt: null,
            progress: 0,
            ships: []
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
        this.countDownInterval = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (!this.state.buttonClickedAt) return;
            const date = new Date();
            const diff = Math.floor((date.getTime() - this.state.buttonClickedAt.getTime()) / 1000);

            if (diff < 90) {
                this.setState({
                    progress: diff,
                    buttonEnabled: false
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    progress: 0,
                    buttonClickedAt: null,
                    buttonEnabled: true
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.countdownInterval);
    }

    async updateRequest() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/hello';
        console.log(url);
        const fetchingData = await fetch(url);
        const ships = await fetchingData.json();

        console.log(ships);

        this.setState({
            buttonEnabled: false,
            buttonClickedAt: new Date(),
            progress: 0,
            ships
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ buttonEnabled: true });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'My_KEY' }}
                    center={{
                        lat: 42.4,
                        lng: -71.1
                    }}
                    zoom={8}
                >
// This will render the customized marker on Google-Map
                    {this.state.ships.map((ship) => (
                        <Ship ship={ship} key={ship.CALLSIGN} lat={ship.LATITUDE} lng={ship.LONGITUDE} />
                    ))}
// This is the dropdown I am trying to update
                    <select className="combo-companies">
                        <option value="All">All</option>
                        <option value="research">research</option>
                        <option value="exploration">exploration</option>
                        <option value="navigation">navigation</option>
                        <option value="drilling">drilling</option>
                    </select>
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**ShipTracker.js**

```
const Ship = ({ ship }) => {
    const shipName = ship.NAME;
    const company = shipCompanyMap[shipName];

    const shipImage = companyImageMap[company];
    return (
        <div>
            {/* Render shipImage image */}
            <img src={shipImage} alt="Logo" />
        </div>
    );
};
export { Ship };

const ShipTracker = ({ ships }) => {
    const handleRowClick = (rowValue) => {
        console.log(rowValue);
    };
    return (
        <div className="ship-tracker">
            <Table className="flags-table" responsive hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Callsign</th>
                        <th>Heading</th>
                        <th>SOG</th>
                        <th>IMO</th>
                        <th>MMSI</th>
                        <th>Longitude</th>
                        <th>Latitudee</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {ships.map((ship, index) => {
                        const { IMO, NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE } = ship;
                        const cells = [ NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, IMO, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE ];
                        return (
                            <tr onClick={() => handleRowClick(ship)} key={index}>
                                <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                                {cells.map((cell) => <td>{cell}</td>)}
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ShipTracker;
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) After investigating I came across [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826065/update-the-value-of-a-dropdown-menu-in-reactjs) which was useful to understand the concept behind the choice. That question remained unanswered and was wondering if the functions  `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` will have to be implemented or if there is an additional way.

2) [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403261/setting-and-updating-state-in-react-js-with-dropdown-component-from-material-ui) was useful too, but made me a bit confused as it seems that there need to be `setState` as an additional function for the implementation.

3) It seems from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339212/updating-state-when-dropdown-select-is-changed-react) that a `response` has to be provided within a handler function.
Although useful I think this post is sum of point 1) + 2).

I know this is a simple example but I was trying to understand the basic concept on how to update a simple `dropdown` before passing to something more intermediate or advanced.
Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: Hello. "This is the dropdown I am trying to update": what do you want to have in this dropdown? The list of the ships?

Comment: Hello, yes correct, together with their logo.

Comment: I just want to fully understand your question. Why do you already have options in your select element?

Comment: I already have choices because I already know their function. I have a `vessel_data.js` which is a template file that looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/LJguSCV.png). And from there I can say the `type` of the vessel. In the image for example that one is a Hopper, another one is a research vessel, another one is a deep sea vessel etc...

Comment: sorry I didn't want to confuse you

Comment: No problem :) So from my understanding, you want to filter the markers from one of the values of the dropdown? For example, only show the markers for the ships with "drilling"?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to achieve :)

Comment: I will update my answer in 5 minutes with a code example.

Comment: that would be great!

Comment: Please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you want to filter the displayed makers on the map regarding the option selected by the user on the dropdown.

You can change the name of `type` with what you want. The type if one of the dropdown values (all, research, exploration, navigation or drilling).

I have not tested the following code, but it should works!

```
class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true,
            buttonClickedAt: null,
            progress: 0,
            ships: [],
            type: 'All'
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
        this.countDownInterval = null;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.type !== prevState.type) {
            // The user has selected a different value from the dropdown
            // To get this value: this.state.type
            // do anything you want here...
            console.log('dropdown value changed for ' + this.state.type);
        }
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            type: e.target.value
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{key: 'My_KEY'}}
                    center={{
                        lat: 42.4,
                        lng: -71.1
                    }}
                    zoom={8}
                >
                    {this.state.ships.filter(ship => ship.type === this.state.type).map((ship) => (
                        <Ship ship={ship} key={ship.CALLSIGN} lat={ship.LATITUDE} lng={ship.LONGITUDE}/>
                    ))}

                    <select className="combo-companies" value={this.state.type} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <option value="All">All</option>
                        <option value="research">research</option>
                        <option value="exploration">exploration</option>
                        <option value="navigation">navigation</option>
                        <option value="drilling">drilling</option>
                    </select>
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. There is a little problem as I have the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` in the function `handleChange(event)`

Comment: [See the print screen I made](https://i.imgur.com/hXpj6iw.png)

Comment: Ok I think is working but I can't see the updated markers as I change selection in the dropdown. Also I should say that I didn't touch `type: e.target.value` Is it because of that?

Comment: Just to explain: you can either add `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);` on the constructor and `handleChange(event) {...}`, or change the method signature for a static method: `handleChange = e => {,,,}`

Comment: You don't have to touch `type: e.target.value`. You can use a `console.log(e.target.value)` in the `handleChange` method to display the value of the selected dropdown option (to verify if you get a value).

Comment: I have also updated the `componentDidUpdate` method with another console.log.

Comment: Oh... I'm sorry! There is infact a typo in the name of the variable. You should change `type: event.target.value` with `type: e.target.value`

Comment: Ok all the logic works correctly. All `console.log()` are saying the correct answer after the selection, but I can't visualize the markers.

Comment: I'm leaving work and I won't be able to answer in the next hour. You need to adapt the filter() method with the data of Ship! It is just an exampel.

Comment: Ok I will try to modify that :)

Comment: filter(ship => ship.type === this.state.type)

I have used ship.type as an example. Do you have a type property on your Ship entity?

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(ship => ship.type === this.state.type)
```

I have used ship.type as an example. Do you have a type property on your Ship entity?

Edit:

```
render() {
    // All the ships
    const ships = this.state.ships;

    // Debug
    console.log('this.state.type: ' + this.state.type);

    // Only the ships matching the dropdown selected value
    const filteredShips = ships.filter(ship => {
        console.log('ship.shipImage: ' + ship.shipImage);

        if (ship.shipImage !== this.state.type) {
            console.log('ship.shipImage does not match the filtered value');
        }

        return ship.shipImage === this.state.type;
    });

    // Debug
    console.log(ships);
    console.log(filteredShips);

    return (
        <div className="google-map">
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{key: 'My_KEY'}}
                center={{
                    lat: 42.4,
                    lng: -71.1
                }}
                zoom={8}
            >
                {filteredShips.map((ship) => (
                    <Ship ship={ship} key={ship.CALLSIGN} lat={ship.LATITUDE} lng={ship.LONGITUDE}/>
                ))}

                <select className="combo-companies" value={this.state.type} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value="All">All</option>
                    <option value="research">research</option>
                    <option value="exploration">exploration</option>
                    <option value="navigation">navigation</option>
                    <option value="drilling">drilling</option>
                </select>
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have `const shipImage = companyImageMap[company];` on my `Ship` entity, that is how I associate the type with the image

Comment: So shipImage is the "type" (in my example)?

Comment: Yes, so the good news is that if I do`filter((ship) => ship.shipImage === this.state.shipImage)` and update the dropdown they all disapperas....so something is happening

Comment: But I still don't understand what the problem could be to show only the selected marker...working on it

Comment: I have updated my answer. With this code you will be able to debug your code and understand why it's not working. First you have to check if the value of `ship.shipImage` is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is the [print screen](https://i.imgur.com/gsFnDO6.png) I am getting. Is this telling you something?

Comment: Yes. It's telling me that the property `shipImage` is always undefined. So, the filter method failed because it compare the selected value (that is OK) with `undefined`. On you ship entity, you have probably a bug with the line `const shipImage = companyImageMap[company];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207685/discussion-between-guicara-and-emanuele).